# pg_dump output contains duplicates

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I have run pg_dump on a database, and restored using pg_restore into a new, entirely empty database, and I get an error:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  could not create unique index "bibleverses_userversestatus_pkey"
DETAIL:  Table contains duplicated values.
```

Examining the table as restored shows a duplicated primary key value, which is stopping the index from being created.

However, examining the original database that the pg_dump comes from does not show this duplicated row - everything is as it should be (and must be, because of the constraint).

How can this happen, and how can it be fixed?

(This is a persistent error, not a one off - running pg_dump again doesn't fix it).

EDIT: Sorry, plain forgot version information: pg_dump/postgres 8.3.11, pg_restore 9.1.6

Comment: are you using `pg_dump` from the same `postgres` version? It is recommended to always use new `pg_dump` binary to dump data from older version

Comment: Which version of Postgresql are you using? There were bugs, related to duplicate key violation, such as this: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/200704161728.l3GHSafh044711@wwwmaster.postgresql.org

Comment: How can a developer ask a question like this an *not* supply the version he uses? Beats me.

Comment: Sorry, version info added now.

Answer (score 0):

First to figure this out you are going to have to take some time with the dump files and find out what is going on.  My immediate guess would be that maybe two backups are getting concatenated together.  But here are things to look at:

1. Are COPY or INSERT statements for a given table occurring multiple times?
2. Can you show that data is being duplicated in a given COPY or INSERT run?
3. Can you duplicate this with both --inserts and without that?

If you can show that it is not caused by concatenating backups together, I would recommend at that point two steps:

1. Upgrade PostgreSQL to the latest 9.1, and test again, and if it still occurs
2. Write up a detailed case and follow up on the pgsql-bugs email list.

I would bet money on it being something like backups being concatenated together but I can't rule out based on the spartan conclusion that there might be a bug.

Comment: What if backups are actually concatenated togheter AND those were the last backups I have? Could there be some way to recover them?

Answer (score 0):

**All sessions to that DB must be revoked during psql restore otherwise it will create duplicate entry issue**

Command to revoke sessions from a specific DB:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE  pid <> pg_backend_pid() AND datname = 'db_name' ;
```

Comment: That's wrong. `pg_dump` create a consistent snapshot of the data at the moment when it started. And transactions that happen after that, are invisible to pg_dump

Comment: But i faced the same issue when i created a schema first  on fresh db and then before restoring the data, my aws lambda created a session with my db and did an entry. It wouldn't let me create a unique index due to double entry. No doubt it varies case to case, i just gave hint regarding this to the other community.